# UnUn for VHF and UHF

Tags: vhf, uhf, impedance-matching, balun

Is it possible to build an UnUn for VHF or UHF like in HF?
Goal is to use a simple endfed wire or piece of metal as an antenna.

EDIT: I meant "endfed halfwave".

Comment: Yes, but not with HF  components.

Comment: Ok, this is obvious, but what are those "non HF" components? Another ferrite ring, or other copper wires?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The matching section of a j-pole is an example of an impedance match device between coax and a monopole antenna. The contacts can be moved up or down the match to accommodate a wide range of impedance.

Depending on your design requirements, you may consider an L configuration dipole or a bazooka configuration dipole (sometimes called a flower pot antenna or dipole because it's also easy to conceal).

Comment: This? https://www.hamradio.me/interests/j-pole

Comment: Not quite an unun -- in fact, the j-pole needs a choke balun.  But it is the 2m end fed half wave version of the HF end fed zepp..

Comment: I dunno, I'd be comfortable calling it an unun since it transforms impedances between two unbalanced systems. It does need an RF choke for sure... I think you typo'd with "choke balun"?